# Securing an AJAX service call in jQuery and PHP (with session token)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm currently building a framework in which for example `form` `submit`'s are being implemented as `jQuery` `ajax` calls to a `.php` (service) file.

Part of the `jQuery` for reference:

```
var dataSerialized = $(form).serialize();
var service = $(form).attr("action");
$.ajax({
    url: "services/" + service + ".php",
    data: dataSerialized,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
        $(json).each(function() {
            loadPage(this.callback);
        });
    },
    error: function(json, message) {
        finalError(message);
    }
});
```

And the `.php` does currently nothing more than:

```
include_once("../content/includes/connect.php");
include_once("_functions.php");

//TODO: support sending variables
$check = true;
$callback = "error";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    list($pass, $errormessage) = checkRules("register", $key, $value);
    if (!$pass) {
        $check = false;
        $callback = "error";
        break;
    }
}

if ($check) {
    $callback = "register_success";
}

echo json_encode(array(
    "callback" => $callback
));

SQL::close();
```

Now I want the service call to be **as secure as possible**, given my situation, I see the following options:

- SSL cannot be used, as it is relatively too expensive. Just working on a homebred project, nothing important.
- jCryption library cannot be used, as I'm on a cheap web hosting and do not have access to the server itself.
- OAuth 2.0 is a possibility, but seems quite complicated.
- `$_SERVER` variables can be used to help protecting the service `.php` pages, but not reliable.
- `$_SESSION` could be used to generate tokens.

I already implemented an easy measure: Change `GET` to `POST`. This will only deter the most easy attack, now the attacker actually needs to use some tampering tool instead of being able to do it directly through the browser.

I think I can protect every call that comes from an `URL` typed in the browser, however I see two serious threats:

1. Direct requests to the webserver: The attacker can pass any data he wants.
2. Using a Browser JavaScript Console to send custom `jQuery` requests.

I think it is best, again under these circumstances, to try to protect the service `.php` pages with `$_SESSION` tokens, but how exactly do I go about these?
They need to be set as some point in time before the service call, and then the service call could check it.
I also have access to a `MySQL` database and of course plain text files on the webspace.

Can anyone help me out any further?

Comment: Why not generate a token based on a current timestamp and verify it later on?

Comment: Do you already have some form of authentication in your web app?

Comment: @Pekka웃 There is no authentication yet. Apart from the regular input checks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a csrf token send together with the form and in your `.php` file you could use something like this

```
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN'] !== $_SESSION['csrfToken']) {
   return false;
    die();
}
```

Send CSRF Token with all service calls

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-Csrf-Token': "TOKEN HERE"
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what it does, where would the token be generated and against what would it protect?

Comment: Make a session variable `$_SESSION['csrfToken']` and assign a random value before the form loads. Assign this variable to a hidden input in your form. Make http header `X-Csrf-Token` the value of this hidden field. That's all.

Comment: I don't want to use PHP in my HTML forms, so I'd have to set/get the token through a service call. Seems like I can't secure it then.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in your form. Alternatively you could use a `<meta content="SESSION TOKEN" name="csrf-token">` tag in the header section and assign it to your ajax header like this `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')`

Comment: I get what you are onto, but is this whole token thing still save if I put it as a service? The thing is that a page on my site only gets loaded once, all other page "loads" are inline AJAX requests.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't. It should work as long as you have `session_start();` in your `.php` file. Test it, if it doesn't work let us know.